# Aurelia - Displaying Static Image

Tags: aurelia

I'm just getting started with Aurelia and I'm having a difficult time including static images when I run my application (in dev). I.e. I have an `img` tag with a `src` pointing to where the image is located in my folder structure, but I continually get a 404 when it's requested. 
I have the image referenced in the `src` attribute of my image tag located in the root of my application, but it's not available when I run my app.

```
<div id="profile-pic">
  <img src="./profilepic.jpg" />
</div>
```

Do I need to modify my aurelia.json file or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL to an image is relative to the page, not to your view. So construct the link as if you were linking to it like that. Typically, your page is `index.html` and is located at the root of your project, alongside the `src` folder. Thus, when you link to an image located inside the `src` folder, you have to include `src` in the path. Thus the following directory structure:

```
my-project
|- index.html
|
 \src
 |-app.js
 |-app.html
 |-profilepic.jpg
```

Will require you to use `<img src="src/profilepic.jpg" />` in your views.

That being said, I would recommend creating a separate folder with your static images in it. This will make it plain that these images are not part of your application source files, but are supporting image content.  You might name this folder `images` and place it in the root of your project, alongside the `src` folder.

```
my-project
|- index.html
|\images
| |-profilepic.jpg
|
 \src
 |-app.js
 |-app.html
```

Then you would use `<img src="images/profilepic.jpg" />` in your views.

Comment: I know like this seems very obvious which is why I'm stumped. I currently have my image in `/src/assets/images`. I've updated my `img` tag `src` to point to this directory. i.e. `assets/images/profilepic.jpg`, but when I run my project the image still doesn't show up in my browser. The error shows it trying to retrieve it from "http://localhost:9000/assets/images/profilepic.jpg".

Comment: You need to add SRC to the beginning of the path. The browser is loading your images relative to the index.html file, not your Aurelia view file.

Comment: That fixed it... I wasn't clear of which directory would be referenced within the running app. I.e. what level I needed to get the relative path from. Thx.